# Current stable xlib wrapper for ruby?

Tags: ruby, x11, xlib, xorg

My project has simple requirements:

1. Grab the contents of an existing xorg app's window
   (do some ocr)
2. Draw something over the existing app's window (to an overlay)

Requirement 2 isn't so important, I could settle for copying the window to my own.

I spent the morning wasting time with limited and out of date projects:

```
hornet's eye (couldn't find how to reference an existing window)
matju's RubyX11 (wanted ruby 1.7)
moriq's ruby-xlib (unsigned int for int errors during compile)
xlib-wrap (more type errors)
```

So apart from using c with xlib or xcb, is there a decent current and stable library or language I can use for fast development? Any language is fine but I would prefer ruby.

Comment: I looked quickly at Hornet's eye. It looks like a pretty promising project. If it can otherwise do what you need, perhaps you can program your own simple Ruby extension to grab a window using C + the Ruby C API. Should not be too hard, then you could feed that to Hornet for the rest of the processing.

Comment: You may want to look at using FFI too.  If there are only a few functions/structs you need to manipulate then it is quick and easy to set up a binding.

Comment: @Casper: Ok I googled and found http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html. Time I learned this I guess.

Comment: Hey..FFI. Didn't know about that one. Good find. You might check that out too. It saves you from having to code C to interface with external libraries.

Comment: Looks like I'm set either way. Thanks both.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I went with [qt4-qtruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/):

```
require 'Qt4'
app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
p = Qt::Pixmap.grabWindow(0x182183b) #param is xlib id from xwininfo
```

Build script I used:

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk libsmokeqt4-dev
cmake \
-DRUBY_EXECUTABLE=`which ruby` \
-DRUBY_INCLUDE_PATH=$MY_RUBY_HOME \
&& make && make install
```

Comment: Teacher badge... Unfortunately grabWindow had a memory leak. I got around it with xwd (and a ramdisk).

Answer (score 1):

I started writing a wrapper around a [subset of Xlib](https://github.com/frankhale/ruby-window-management). I wrapped quite a bit. You may want to look at the C code and Ruby examples and hack on this to make it do what you want.